# background-color of marked child menu item does not change

Tags: css, menu, menuitem

my problem is that always the marked item has a blue background color. However, I want to have the parent and the marked child item to have a blue background color.

I tried different things but none of them worked.
The programm is written partly in jsp, javascript, gwt, and rcp. So it was not possible for me to debug the code. Nonetheless, I found the stylesheet where the problem should be.
Maybe someone can help me please.
Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    .menu-Menu {
        margin-top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234);
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .menu-Menu.vertical {
        background-image: url(../images/bg/some.gif);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
    }

    .menu-Menu.horizontal {
        background-image: url(../images/bg/horizon.gif);
    }

    .menu-MenuItem {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .vertical .menu-MenuItem {
        padding: 1px;
    }

    .horizontal .menu-MenuItem {
        float:left;
        padding: 2px;
        background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
    }

    .menu-MenuItem-active {
        background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
        background-image: url(../images/bg/vertical.gif);
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-position: -1px 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .vertical .menu-MenuItem-active, .vertical .menu-MenuItem-active-disabled 
    {
    }

    .horizontal .menu-MenuItem-active, .horizontal .menu-MenuItem-active-
     disabled {
    background-color: inherit;
    background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
    }

    .menu-MenuItem-active-disabled {
        border: 1px solid rgb(255, 189, 105);
        background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
    }

    .vertical .menu-MenuItem-label {
        padding-left: 16px;
    }

    .horizontal .menu-MenuItem-label {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
    }

    .horizontal .menu-MenuItem-label-padding {
        padding-right: 18px;
    }

    .horizontal .menu-MenuItem-right-panel {
        padding-right: 18px;
    }

    .menu-MenuItem-inactive div,
    .menu-MenuItem-inactive span {
        color: #4286f4;
    }

    .menu-MenuItem-inactive img {
        filter: gray() alpha(opacity=30);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well since it's required in order to identify the problem. Assuming that your menu uses an ul / li structure, you should probably try, for example, to have the blue color to be applied to the active menu item's parent ul as well (e.g. <ul class="menu-Menu active"><li class="menu-MenuItem"><a href="#">Menu item</a></li><li class="menu-MenuItem-active"><a href="#">Active item</a></li></ul>)

Comment: Currently, that is the problem, because it is written in GWT as it seems. So, I am not sure whether it is using <li> or something else. Installing a debugger for GWT did not succeed. Nonetheless, I will go on and hopefully I will find something.

Comment: So, I found the corresponding java class where Menuwidget and everything else is being instantiated. I will go through this class - does somebody know how to mark parent and child? Currently, it does look like this: Parent - Child - Subchild and if the last one is selected only the last one gets marked. I have a lot of parent with plenty of children and subchildren. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. There is a class where the mouse click is recognized and there I do the following:

```
Element element = DOM.eventGetToElement(event);
element.setPropertyString("xxx", "class");
```

Thanks for your help.